# respond with redirect on json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using a bootstrap typeahead plugin. Basically, it expects a json response when you click on one of the items in the dropdown menu. However, when the item is clicked, I want to redirect to a different page; I do not want to respond with json. I don't know how to handle this situation. This is what I have:

```
  def populate_global_search
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:name] && params[:name][:value]
        model = Model.where(name: params[:name][:value]
      else
        model = nil
      end

      if model.present?
        format.json { redirect_to model }
      else
        format.json { head :ok}
      end
    end
  end
```

The action is triggered from an ajax call:

```
$(element).bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: that.format_url(),
    data: {
      name : datum
    }
  }).done(function(data){
    ...
```

Since the redirect_to is not a json response, nothing happens when I click on the item. What can I do?

Comment: How is you call this action?

Comment: @Зелёный action is called from bootstrap typeahead http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: ok, is some `ajax`? Could you share the code?

Comment: @Зелёный yes I use jquery $.ajax when the item is selected

Comment: cool, __show me the code__ please.

Comment: @Зелёный code added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here, you call the `populate_global_search` action asynchronously, `respond_to` block unable to redirect an asynchronously call. To resolve your problem I suggest you render the path to redirect and change the location by [`window.location`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp):

The javascript code(that's just an assumption):

```
$(element).bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: that.format_url(),
    data: {
      name : datum
    }
  }).done(function(data){
    // redirect to the desired path
    window.location = data.location;
  });
```

The Rails code(also assumption):

```
def populate_global_search
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:name] && params[:name][:value]
        # I use find_by, because where return a collection
        model = Model.find_by(name: params[:name][:value])
      else
        model = nil
      end

      if model.present?
        # render a json objects { location: '/some_path/12' } 
        # with path which you need
        format.json { render json: { location: here_is_the_desired_path } }
      else
        format.json { head :ok }
      end
    end
  end
```

Bonus, your can reduce your Rails code to, this also should works:

```
def populate_global_search
  model = Model.find_by(name: params[:name].try(:[], :value))
  if model.present?
    render json: { location: here_is_the_desired_path }
  else
    head :ok
  end
end
```